# PHP autoload function stops working

Tags: php, autoload

I have a PHP project. It contains a 'classes' folder and the folder has PHP classes.

I set up the autoload function according this manual: [PHP manual](http://function%20my_autoloader($class)%20%7B%20%20%20%20%20include%20'classes/'%20.%20$class%20.%20'.class.php';%20%7D%20%20spl_autoload_register('my_autoloader');) and everything was working well, until I have renamed 3 classes and added 4 other classes to the 'classes' directory. After that, It stopped working.

I have also tried to set up full directory path, but it didn't help. If I use `require_one` manually, it works fine.

Is it possible, that the folder contain too many PHP class file?

There is the code:

```
require_once './classes/Requirement.php';

function allClass_autoloader($class) {
    require_once 'classes/' . $class . '.php';
}

spl_autoload_register('allClass_autoloader');

 $mysqli = SConnectionFactory::createConnection($SERVER, $DB_USERNAME, $DB_PASSWORD, $DATABASE);
                $selectUserQuery = "SELECT email, name, type, regist FROM user";
```

And the classes folder contains the SConnectionFactory.php file.

I have run a debug and I put a breakpoint into the allClass_autoloader function. The `$class` variable get the `SConnectionFactory` value. The `$selectUserQuery` variable doesn't get any value. So I'm a little bit confused.

Comment: could you add your code and folder architecture as well?

Comment: Most likely your class name and file names simply do not correspond any more.

Comment: @arkascha - I kept in mind this thing and at first, I refactor the name of the classes and then, rename the class name.

Comment: I mentioned the _file_ names... This is mandatory for the autoload feature to work as expected.

Comment: Sorry, I wanted to write _file_ name instead of the class name, but my time is left to edit my comment.

Comment: It would probably be best if you included a rough directory structure and where this was failing.